# Record multiple data into a single variable

Tags: objective-c, global-variables

Problem: The user enters the number of 10-bit, you need to calculate the sum of all the digits.

I'm trying to type variable "int a [10] = {}" but it does not work, can I write in it a few results?

Write sample code please.

Comment: Do you mean `number of 10-digits`, yes? If yes, it's an `int` value, you can't store single digits in an array directly.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't specified which language are you using, so I answer to you supposing you are coding in java.

In order to do what you asked for, you have to do this:

```
int number = 454685; // = an example number
    int[] arr = new int [6]; // array of int, 6 = digits of the number
    int i = 0; // counter
    while (number > 0) {
        arr[i] = number % 10; //stores in arr[i] the last digit
        i++; //increment counter
        number = number / 10; //divides the number per 10 to cancel the last digit (already stored in arr[i])
    }
    int sum = 0; //declares the sum variable
    i = 0; //reset counter
    do{
        sum = sum + arr[i];
        i++;
    }while( i < arr.length); //this loop calculates the sum
    System.out.println(sum); //prints the sum of the digits
```

Here you are.

Comment: @user2520114 then take a look at this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2303125/extracting-digits-from-integer-and-decimal-parts-of-a-double and this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15728816/how-to-split-integer-into-component-digits